# How to post to a Spray.io REST service from an HTML Form?

Tags: spray

I have a simple REST service hosted in spray.io. If I call the service from an http client passing JSON, I can marshall json-encoded data to an entity and everything works fine.

However, HTML forms can't post json, so how do I convert form-encoded data to an entity in the spray endpoint (route)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to extract form data on your endpoint. You can use `formField` and `formFields` directive: http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/form-field-directives/formFields/#formfields

Take a look at http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/#longer-example, specifically the following part:

```
    // method tunneling via query param
(put | parameter('method ! "put")) {
  // form extraction from multipart or www-url-encoded forms
  formFields('email, 'total.as[Money]).as(Order) { order =>
    complete {
      // complete with serialized Future result
      (myDbActor ? Update(order)).mapTo[TransactionResult]
    }
  }
```